# Different DNS points to same server but access to a different directory

Tags: nginx

#### Issue

When I entered `domainB.com` URL it will force a redirect to `domainA.com` or it would display the `domainA` content while the URL is showing `domainB.com`

#### Expected Outcome

I am expecting the `domainA.com` and `domainB.com` would display its own content respectively, which mean

- `domainA.com` showing the content in `var/www/DomainA`
- `domainB.com` showing the content in `var/www/DomainB`

#### Nginx Config

```
# domainA.com
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domainA.com;

    if ($host = "www.domainA.com") {
            return 301 https://www.domainA.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    server_name domainA.com www.domainA.com;

    root /var/www/resume;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domainA.com/domainA.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domainA.com/domainA.com.key;

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

```
# domainB.com

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.domainB.com;

    if ($host = subdomain.domainB.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    return 404;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name subdomain.domainB.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domainB.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domainB.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    root /var/www/simple-crm/ui/dist;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        auth_basic "Cady's Personal Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        root /var/www/simple-crm/ui/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

#### What am I trying to achieve

I want the website to display the correct content based on the URL I have entered.

Comment: Maybe your configuration for `domainB` is wrong - it says `server_name subdomain.domainB.com;` where it should be `server_name domainB.com;` ?

Comment: @papanito, I solved the problem. I just need to combine all the nginx config into one and it fixed the problem.